# How can i ignore user messages in MS Bot framework using direct line channel

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have created a bot in one scenario it will call an API and it will take same time to get the output from that API, if in between user type anything it will start working on the text which user sent recently. I want till API output is not received, if user sent any messages it will get ignored.

Comment: That would be quite difficult to do, you'd have to create something in the api that would keep track of received messages from users and almost queues them.

Comment: Are you using the DirectLine API or a DirectLine client like Web Chat or the DirectLineJs npm package?

Comment: @tdurnford : I am using DirectLine Web Chat, Actually there is option to connect the live agent if bot is not able to answer the user query, then request is going the Agent and by the time he will accept the request, if user type anything that requests is getting cancelled and again new workflow is getting started so i want till bot will get the any response from the Live chat agent it should not consider any user messages.

Comment: Which BotBuilder SDK are you using - Node or C#? For WebChat, are you using a CDN, iFrame, or React? React would be the simplest solution, but it’s possible with the cdn. Unfortunately, the embedded iFrame is not flexible enough to accomplish this.

Comment: I am using C#, got the solution, Thanks a lot for you help.
I am setting one session when user is requesting to talk with Live Agent, then i am checking if that session is in progress and any new message is coming then i am just ignoring them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am setting one session when user is requesting to talk with Live Agent, Then i am checking if that session is in progress and any new message is coming from user then i am just ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

If your bot is integrated into some app then you can actually disable the send button until you receive an answer for the previous question.